# How to make background-image size maintain its proportions?

Tags: html, background-image, css

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/SJUeK/

I want for a background image in example to be always its full height (dependent on width). I can't do it with pixels, because it needs to be responsive.

Is there a way to do that? Or need I to use img in html?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Sure:

```
background-size: auto 100%;
```

[Here's a demo.](http://dabblet.com/gist/3700723)

Or if you actually meant "maintain its aspect ratio and scale to fit inside the container", then `background-size: contain` should do the trick.

Comment: Using 'background-size: auto 100%;' I get image that is of height of my element - extremely small: http://jsfiddle.net/SJUeK/7/

'background-size: contain' is doing the same for me. Maybe the way I described it was not clear (bad english, quite new to css) but I wanted it to have width as in example and only height being scaled to "maintain its aspect ratio". 

In my case <li> element has heigth of text. So maybe my question should be: How to make element height to "inherit" height of its background image?

Comment: @jukooz: Oh, elements can't scale to their background images. You'll need an `<img>`, unless your images are all the same height.

Comment: So what is the good way to make scalable navigation with background image for <li> item?

Answer (score 0):

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/